# Should an ending semicolon be underlined?

Tags: punctuation, semicolons

Should the semicolon at the end of an underlined heading also be underlined?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The general rule [seems to be](http://grammar.ccc.commnet.edu/grammar/grammarlogs3/grammarlogs492.htm) to include the punctuation in the underlined text only if it is an integral part of the final word. This would include initialisms such as **U.S.** and special cases such as the musical **Oklahoma!**

Otherwise, if the punctuation is simply to end the piece of text — such as a period, semi-colon, and so on — it should not be underlined.

Answer (score 3):

In the good ol' days of the typewriter, we would carefully avoid underlining punctuation marks, esp., the period, comma, colon, semicolon, etc., because all or part of the punctuation mark would be obscured by the underline.

Answer (score 2):

Why are you underlining text?  In HTML parlance, adhering punctuation marks are not placed inside of a link.  For example:

> This is a very useful `<a href="http://www.google.com">link</a>`; use it when you want to find stuff.

Underlining text, to me, seems  to be an anachronism that goes back to the typewriter.

Comment: Apologies, jumped in and changed your example code to a link without thinking... now rolled back.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps I do this wrong in my own writing, but I do not underline punctuation (comma, period, exclamation point, question mark, colon, semicolon, etc) when the preceding word is underlined unless that punctuation mark is part of the title, as in Oklahoma! or Stomp!.

Underlining text is certainly not an  "anachronism that goes back to the typewriter" because in MLA (Modern Language Association) format, APA (American Psychological Association) format, etc, underlining is one of the several ways specified to refer to books.

Answer (score 1):

> Underlining text is certainly not an "anachronism that goes back to the typewriter" because in MLA (Modern Language Association) format, APA (American Psychological Association) format, etc, underlining is one of the several ways specified to refer to books.

I realize this topic is old but I did just want to post an update for anyone who comes across this- official MLA guidelines now prefer italicized book titles instead of underlined, unless someone is writing by hand, in which case underlining may be used.

Comment: Please attribute your quote.

Comment: @JJJ Scroll down to the bottom of this page - it might be what Kaleo is referring to: https://owl.purdue.edu/owl/general_writing/punctuation/punctuation/index.html

Answer (score 0):

As I learned in Typing in both high school and Business School -- you do not underline punctuation!  You end the underline under the last word, unless it is a title.  Where did "anachronism that goes back to typewriter" person pick up their knowledge -- Twitter?